# Very light queries are in slow-query-log ! Why?

Tags: mysql, performance

I try to optimize my websites, because MySQL falled in timeout.
I've simplied queries and added indexes.
Server works fine, but in log stil some queries.

Amazing ! : the only queries on the slow-query-log are very simple and light queries. I don't understand !...
Can you help me ?

My site is on Private MySql servor, OVH.
Logs extract :

```
# Time: 170109 18:17:04
# User@Host: doctsfgl[doctsfgl] @  [10.0.83.198]  Id: 837382
# Query_time: 1.185552  Lock_time: 0.000117 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1483982224;
delete from gl_visiteurs 
                where IP like '68.180.230.33';
# Time: 170109 18:17:05
# User@Host: doctsfgl[doctsfgl] @  [10.0.83.198]  Id: 837382
# Query_time: 1.440233  Lock_time: 0.000151 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1483982225;
INSERT INTO gl_visiteurs (IP, user_id) 
                VALUES ('68.180.230.33',0);
# Time: 170109 18:17:20
# User@Host: doctsfgl[doctsfgl] @  [10.0.83.92]  Id: 837412
# Query_time: 2.540715  Lock_time: 0.000124 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1483982240;
delete from gl_visiteurs 
                where IP like '109.220.253.15';
# Time: 170109 18:40:36
# User@Host: doctsfgl[doctsfgl] @  [10.0.83.198]  Id: 839694
# Query_time: 1.566650  Lock_time: 0.000095 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1483983636;
delete from gl_visiteurs 
                where IP like '66.249.64.218';
```

These queries, when executed in PhpMyAdmin, run in very short laps, about 0.01 s !!!
All columns concerned are indexed. 
Table contain less than 100 records, and 3 columns !...

An idea ?
Many thanks
(sorry for my english ; I'm french)

The create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gl_visiteurs 
( IP varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  start timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  logue int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Indices:

```
ALTER TABLE gl_visiteurs 
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (IP,user_id), 
 ADD KEY user_id (user_id), 
 ADD KEY start (start), 
 ADD KEY IP (IP);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using *like* instead of *=* ? If you can always expect the system to store complete IP addresses, then there's no reason to have the *like* operator.

Comment: Show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE gl_visiteurs;` output.

Comment: No reason. I usually do that, maybe it is not the best way. I'll replace with '='

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gl_visiteurs` (
  `IP` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `start` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `logue` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: You either changed the output or the table has no indexes at all.

Comment: Sorry : 
ALTER TABLE `gl_visiteurs`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`IP`,`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `start` (`start`),
  ADD KEY `IP` (`IP`);

Comment: The `IP` index is likely not needed or used at all, since the PK is `(IP, user_id)`. But not sure if that has anything to do with the slow queries.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are searching for an IP address

You could add an additional column with a numeric value for the IP

First, create the column to hold the numeric value of the IP and index it

```
ALTER TABLE gl_visiteurs ADD COLUMN IPVALUE INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
```

Next populate that new column and index it

```
UPDATE gl_visiteurs SET IPVALUE = INET_ATON(IP);
ALTER TABLE gl_visiteurs ADD INDEX (IPVALUE);
```

From there, you can do deletes via numeric lookups like this

```
delete from gl_visiteurs 
where IPVALUE = INET_ATON('68.180.230.33');
```

and do inserts like this

```
INSERT INTO gl_visiteurs (IP, IPVALUE, user_id) 
VALUES ('68.180.230.33',INET_ATON('68.180.230.33'),0);
```

## UPDATE 2017-01-09 17:57 EST

[Based on your comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160443/very-light-queries-are-in-slow-query-log-why#comment308304_160454), you can drop the IP column and keep the IPVALUE column

Then your inserts would be

```
INSERT INTO gl_visiteurs (IPVALUE, user_id) 
VALUES (INET_ATON('68.180.230.33'),0);
```

but to see the IP your selects must be something like

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(IPVALUE) as IP,... FROM gl_visiteurs
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Inet_aton is new for me ! Great, thanks !

Comment: OK, done. But in insert statment, why keep "IP" ? Redondant with IPVALUE, and no more usefull ?

Comment: Hello, idem : these 2 queries (delete and insert) take 1,5s via PHP, and only 0.01 via phpMyAdmin. A great great mystery !...

Answer (score 0):

Here are several thoughts; none of which are definite answers:

Check to see if you have `log_queries_not_using_indexes` turned on.  I find that to be virtually useless, and clutter the slowlog with unnecessary entries, such as you are finding.

What `CHARACTER SET` are you connected with?  I see you are doing `LIKE` (unnecessarily) against a `latin1` column.  Use `=` if you are not using wild cards.

Please provide `EXPLAIN ...` for some of those queries; there may be some surprises.

So you have other queries touching the table?  They could be interfering, thereby slowing down these queries.

Since the `PRIMARY KEY` starts with `IP`, `KEY IP (IP)` is redundant, and should be `DROPped`.

Since the PK is necessarily `UNIQUE`, you are limiting the entries in this table to be one per user per IP?

Provide `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` some time when the problem occurs.  It is likely to have some clues.

Are these statements part of a `BEGIN...COMMIT` transaction?  If so, let's see more of the transaction.  Note: If you are running with `autocommit=0`, you are in a transaction.

Do you really have a `user_id=0`, as indicated in your `INSERT` example?

Comment: Many thanks for the help.
 
I cannot enable log_queries_not_using_indexes :
"set global log_queries_not_using_indexes = 'ON'"  give 
"Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation".
I'm on shared servor, (OVH mutualisé)


Character set is actually UTF8
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
I just change latin1 to Utf8_general_CI
I already changed "like" with "="
 
Explain on insert query give :
id 1
Select type SIMPLE
1 SIMPLE NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL No tables used

Comment: Sorry for the line breaks !...  
  "End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak:" do not effect !???  
No other queries touching the table.    
  OK I delete redundant IP key    
  I've not enough privilege for SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;    
  No transaction    
  Yes, I have user_id =0 users : not logged users